# How do I remove a tr then apply background-color to odd tr's?

Tags: jquery, html-table

on doc.ready, I've done `$("tr:even").css("background-color","orange");`.  I then have a button that does the following: `$("#tr3).remove()` which removes the 3rd tr (I id'ed the third tr "tr3").  I then apply the orange bgcolor to even rows AGAIN in order to update the tr bgcolors now that the table has 1 less tr, but the tr bgcolor's don't refresh.  I end up with 2 orange tr's in a row, instead of having every other tr be orange background.  make sense?

Comment: When posting a question like this it is most helpful just to show the code you're talking about. Can you edit your question and add your javascript code?

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier if you made that background color a css class:

```
.odd { background-color: orange; }
```

Then in javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $("tr:even").addClass("odd");
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $("#tr3").remove();
    $("tr").removeClass("odd").filter(":nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 Classes are **much** better than using `css()` for this kind of thing. Just what I was going to say (if it hadn't already been said).

Answer (score 1):

try applying also on the odd one:

```
$("tr:odd").css("background-color","your color");
$("tr:even").css("background-color","orange");
```

as I think it is because when you remove the 3rd tr, all tr next to it changes. the odd becomes even and the even becomes odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to access the nth element:

```
$("tr:nth-child(3n)") //will match with 3rd, 6th, ...
```

you can change `3n` or do simple add and substract to it:

```
$("tr:nth-child(3n+1)") //will match with 1st, 4th, 7th, ...
$("tr:nth-child(3n+2)") //will match with 2nd, 5th, 8th, ...
```

`:nth` can be used in filter too, for example:

```
$(SELECTOR).filter(":nth-child(3n)")
```

I hope this is what you looking for.

UPDATE:

After re-read your question, I thing I got it wrong.

In my code, I put the code in separated function:

```
function zebra_table($) {
  $("tr").removeClass("odd");
  $("tr:odd").addClass("odd");
}
```

Then after I change the table's row, such as delete one of it, or add new row, I will simply call the function above:

```
jQuery(function($){
  //after DOM loaded, apply zebra
  zebra_table($);

  //...
  //after modify table
  zebra_table($);
});
```

The key is, make the table 'plain' again, then re-apply the zebra rules in the current table structure.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the responses!  I will try this when I get home (I'm at work and this is a side project. I don't like to mix the two :P )

Answer (score 0):

All, thanks so much for your help!!!  I ended up doing the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("#button").click(function () {
        $("#tr3").remove();
        $("tr").removeClass("odd");
        $("tr:odd").addClass("odd"); // re-add class to odd tr's
    });
});
```

and that worked!  Didn't need to do any filter(n) stuff.  Thanks again for the help!!!